# Inheritance with appsettings.json settings in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

- BaseSettings   - has settings common to all other sections
- Child1Settings - has all BaseSettings + Child1Settings
- Child2Settings - has all BaseSettings + Child2Settings

  [...]
- ChildNSettings - has all BaseSettings + ChildNSettings

So then I'd have this in my controllers:

```
public class Child1Controller : Controller
{
    public Child1Controller(Child1Settings settings)
    {
        // settings.BaseSetting and settings.Child1Setting should both be accessible here
    }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
public class BaseSettings
{
    public string BaseSetting { get; set; }
}

public class Child1Settings : BaseSettings
{
    public string Child1Setting { get; set; }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "BaseSettings": {
        "BaseSetting": "BaseSettingValue"
    },
    "Child1Settings": {
        "Child1Setting": "Child1SettingValue"
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<Child1Settings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("Child1Settings").Get<Child1Settings>());
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
}
```

That populates the Child1Settings fields just fine, but not the BaseSettings fields. I could see this working (though I haven't tried), but this feels ridiculous and would lead to a LOT of redundancy and potential error if I were to have many child setting classes:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Child1Settings": {
        "BaseSettings": {
            "BaseSetting": "BaseSettingValue"
        }
        "Child1Setting": "Child1SettingValue"
    },
    "Child2Settings": {
        "BaseSettings": {
            "BaseSetting": "BaseSettingValue"
        }
        "Child2Setting": "Child2SettingValue"
    }
}
```

Comment: First, when you remove `BaseSettings` and put the `BaseSetting` on the same level as `Child1Setting`, it should work. However the really **ridiculous** thing is to ask such specific and rarely used features for a system which is meant to allow simple reading/serializing to support all rarely and improbable use cases. How do you expect this even to work in the first place, without some complex. How should the config even know that your object shall be an "inherited", you are specifically passing a key `Configuration.GetSection("Child1Settings")` which selects exactly **ONE** element

Comment: Any attempts to add any kind of inheritance would require a quite complex json schema, which would make working with it too complicated for most case. If you need something specific you'd need to write your own solution or use 3rd party extensions if there some exist to read configuration from other sources. Behind the scenes its just a simple json deserialization and it requires all properties to be set on the json object when assigning it. That's how JSON works, since neither json nor JavaScript (where it originally comes from) have a concept of inheritance

Comment: I don't understand what you guys are taking about. This isn't that complex and a useful approach for not having to duplicate configuration. I think it's a great question! 

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this is by configure your child with base section data then configure it with child specific data like this:

```
services.Configure<Child1Settings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("BaseSettings"));
services.Configure<Child1Settings>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("Child1Settings"));
```

This way the first call to `Configure<Child1Settings>` will configure it with base data. The next call to `Configure<Child1Settings>` will override what you have configured in the BaseSettings and add the additional Child1Settings to it.

Comment: Wow +1 this really works! I was looking for a way to bind sibling sections. Thank you!

Comment: Great suggestion. Solved my problem on the spot!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Child1Settings` is a descendant class it includes all properties of the base class. Try this:

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Child1Settings": {
        "BaseSetting": "BaseSettingValue"
        "Child1Setting": "Child1SettingValue"
    }
}
```

Keep you `Startup.cs` as it is:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<Child1Settings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("Child1Settings").Get<Child1Settings>());
    services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
```

This will allow you to use both `settings.BaseSetting` and `settings.Child1Setting` in your controller. It will also allow you to specify separate `BaseSettings` per child.

That being said, I would personally avoid this setup as it complicates things. When you look at `Child1Settings` class you cannot tell right away what settings are available, you have to follow the inheritance path. To avoid this you can change `BaseSettings` to an interface (`IBaseSettings`) that `ChildSettings` classes need to implement. This ensures that all descendant classes include the base settings but forces you to repeat all the settings in each descendant class so that it is always straightforward to see what settings are available in each section.

On the other hand, if you want to have one common `BaseSettings` section, you don't need inheritance at all. Just inject both `BaseSettings` and `Child1Settings` in the controller constructor.