# Create configuration class with interitance from base class without duplication in config.json

Tags: c#, inheritance, configuration

I have a few similar classes with similar configurations in it.

So, I want to create a base Class with common configuration, after that inherit it in child config class and in the end initialize it in logic class:

```
public class OptionsBase
{
    public string ConnectionKey { get; set; }            
}


public class OptionsChild: OptionsBase
{
    public string ChildName{ get; set; }
}
```

My json file:

```
"OptionsBase": {
  "ConnectionKey": "basekey"
},
"OptionsChild": {
  "ChildName" "child1"
}
```

Expecting to use it like this:

```
public class Child1
{
    private readonly OptionsChild _options;

    public Child1(IOptions<OptionsChild> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public void Example()
    {
        var valueFromParent = _options.ConnectionKey;
    }
}
```

How can I do it without duplication in json file and without using additional common class with common options?

It is web app, config initialization executed like this:

```
service.Configure<OptionsChild>(config.GetSection("OptionsChild"));
```

Thank you!

EDIT: I found the solution and added an answer. Please, let me know if the solution is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53547293/13969337) it is described, exactly what I wanted to receive.

It is a bit workaround, need to configure each configuration class twice, but this way I can use base options without duplicating options in child options class and also I don't need to duplicate configuration in JSON file

Please, let me know if the solution is OK.

Comment: use comment instead of posting it as answer